# How to plot top k variables by variables importance of xgboost in python?

Tags: python, variables, xgboost

In python, how can I plot the top k variables by variableI importance?

When I use the `xgb.plot_importance`, it always plot all of the variables trained in the model.

However, I have over 3000 features and I don't want to plot them all; I only care about top 100 variables with strong influence.

I know that I can extract variable importance from `xgb_model.get_score()`, which returns a dictionary storing pairs (features, importance). Maybe this is the direction that I can extract top k important variables from the dictionary.

But I don't know how to create a pictures(histogram) with the same style like `xgb.plot_importance` does if I manually plot according to the top k dictionary.

Or is there any way that I can plot top k variables depends on the xgboost build-in API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `'max_num_features'` param in `xgb.plot_importance()`.

From [the documentation](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.plot_importance):

> max_num_features (int, default None) – Maximum number of top features
>   displayed on plot. If None, all features will be displayed.

So use it like this:

```
xgb.plot_importance(..., ..., ..., max_num_features = 100)
```